# My toilet seat is loose

Tags: toilet

My toilet seat has been loose for a few weeks now. I would like to fix it. I am unable to access the area where the screws are. I have attached some photos to show how I am unable to access the toilet. [image]

[image]

Comment: The 2nd pic indicates that you need to reach under the back of the porcelain to find the nut/bolt that holds the seat down. I don't think there's anything at all you need to do with the seat/lid itself, beyond hold it in position.

Answer (score 15):

Here's your problem right here.

[image]

There'll be a **vertical screw** going straight down through the porcelain toilet bowl.  If you follow that imaginary vertical line, you'll find some sort of recess or pocket providing access to the "nut" on the bottom.

Expect a plastic cartoon version of a nut that is designed to be tightened by hand; it's normal for those pockets to be confined enough to make it hard to get tools in there.  Or if not the pocket, the working space lol.   Sometimes the nuts get sticky and need some persuading, but improvise what you need - I've used a huge 1-1/8" hex socket that fit over the plastic nut, I've used pliers, etc.

DO NOT go down to the hardware store and get actual metal nuts of that same thread.  The cartoon nut is plastic for a reason; using metal hardware will easily crack the porcelain and then you need a new toilet. *Been there, done that (the guy before me had selected metal hardware; I just tightened it without thinking)*.

Now you're saying "I know about *that* loose nut; I choose not to fix it and want to fix the problem I stated" -- but they're related.  One is causing the other.

Comment: It might be just me lucky but the latest lids I have all came with a plastic "wrench" that makes it easy to reach into the recess and tighten the nut. Might be just that I don't buy the cheapest one I find. :-)

Comment: my toilet also came with a plastic wrench tool that is custom designed to make tightening easy. **do not throw it away. keep it.** (i had to buy the toilet seat again to get the tool.) you have to tighten it about once every 1.5 years (if used more than requires more tightening).

Comment: The last toilet seat that I installed (about a year ago?) actually called for using a metal wrench or socket set.  The plastic nut at the bottom actually had two parts, with the bottom part shearing off when you had reached the level of torque that they wanted.  (and then the top part so you could take it back off if needed).

Answer (score 13):

There should be a button to press which will release the seat from its hinge post on either side. If it's not the large silver knob then it may be hidden:
[image]

The pic below is from a toilet similar to yours, and may help with figuring it out. It shows how the seat hinges slide and clip onto the hinge posts mounted on the toilet:
[image]
<sub>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1585/4485/files/SM-WT530_530MB_Manual.pdf?v=1598974159</sub>

Comment: Unlikely. This lid seems to be of simpler construction, just the bolt going down. As mentioned in the other answer, those nuts are usually plastic (I don't think just to save two cents, more likely to reduce the chance of overtightening and breaking the bowl; well, Harper mentioned this too, I should have read more carefully), so they can get loose or broken.

Comment: Ugh, those clip-on ones are the worst.  I moved into a place that had one of the clip-on seats, and no matter how you tightened it, it would pop loose again every week or so.  I eventually threw the thing out and replaced it with the traditional plastic screw type and it's lasted for years without need of further maintenance.

Comment: Yeah believe you me, you really, really want the failure point to be the "cheap" plastic bolt/nut.  Because otherwise it will be the porcelain toilet.